# Page sorting in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql

I try to add custom paging  and when I login through username and password, an error occurs.
Also I show document only his/her documents like when abc is login then abc only able to view her documents, but when I add custom paging it show me error `UserID` is not supplied and I also share sp code

Code is

```
protected void BindRepeater()
{
    SqlConnection con = new          
    SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydms"].
    ConnectionString.ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sphrdoc2", con);

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(dt);
    PagedDataSource pgitems = new PagedDataSource();
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
```

In this line

```
 adp.Fill(dt);
```

error occurs

> Procedure or function 'sphrdoc2' expects parameter '@UserID', which was not supplied.

sp is

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sphrdoc2]

    @UserID int
    as
    Select 
       dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID, 
       dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName, 

       dbo.DocType.DocType as Document, 

       dbo.Department.DepType as Department, 
       dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded,
       dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType AS Status 

       FROM 
       dbo.DocumentInfo
           inner JOIN dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
           inner JOIN dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID
           left join dbo.ApproveType on dbo.DocumentInfo.ApproveID=dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID
       where UserID=@UserID
```

Any one tell me where I done mistake in repeater code?

Comment: Let's see... maybe you forgot to pass the parameter `@userID`?

Comment: Hi where you call that procedure? do you pass the parameter? dont forget use the same type of parameter

Comment: i calling the store procedure in this   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sphrdoc2", con);

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass parameters for your stored procedure .

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sphrdoc2", con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID","YourUserID"); 
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: @user2931015 Your userId which you have maintained in session variable or may be in Querystring

Comment: i done use querystring i use session like this    int user_id =Convert.ToInt16( aa.sppplogin(txt_username.Value, txt_pass.Value));
            Session["UserID"] = user_id;
                if (Session["UserID"] != null)
                {
                    user_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"].ToString());
                }

Comment: and i use like this             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID",Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]));
but it still show me error

Comment: error  adp.Fill(dt);

error occur Procedure or function 'sphrdoc2' expects parameter '@UserID', which was not supplied.